# Find pattern HH:MM in Notepad++ with a regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using the latest version of Notepad++.

I have a text file and I want to delete all the characters except this one: (14:32).

The text if a list of lessons in a online course and I want to extract the time to sum all of them because I want to know how long it is.This is an example of the text:

```
Lecture 1.
    Programming robots (15:32)
    Understanding ROS (8:20)
```

I want to remove everything to get something like this:

```
(15:32)
(8:20)
```

I have tried these regular expressions:

```
^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$

/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]$/
```

But I can't find anything with them.

How can I find this pattern in Notepad++?

Maybe, it could be easier find all the characters ([a-z][A-Z]) and replace them with nothing.

Comment: `^.*(\((?:[0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\)).*` -> `$1`

Comment: Remove `^` and `$` charcters from your pattern, as they mark the start and end of the line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

*Find What*: `^.*(\((?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\)).*`
*Replace With*: `$1`

[image]

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sTW78z/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(\((?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\))` - Group 1:

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])` - an optional `0` or `1` digit, and then any one digit, or `2` and then a digit from `0` to `3` range
  - `:` - a `:` char
  - `[0-5][0-9]` - minutes part (a digit from `0` to `5` and then any one digit)
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `.*` - the rest of the line.